# How to upgrade a single program in a container owning several ones?

Tags: docker

I have built a docker App image which owns several programs to run for a service. It's very convenient to start a service just by using `docker run`. But, I find that it's inconvenient to bug fix one of these programs by using the bug-fixed version to replace the origin one. I can try rebuild the image but it needs to firstly stop the container which means I have to stop the all the processes of the  service. I want to know is there any methods like just stopping one process, replacing the exe and restarting to upgrade for this case? Is it a good way to make an image contain a whole service with several programs, or should each a program an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you should look into docker-compose.  Make each program a separate image and use a compose file to bring them up as a group.